# Why am i getting a stack overflow? Advice would be greatly appreciated

Tags: c++

So, I'm very new to coding and i do apologize beforehand if my code makes you cringe. I have a coding homework to write a program that displays the c_string in all uppercase characters using a recursive function. When running my code, i get an out put of "A" then i get a stack overflow and i don't know why. Please assist me to help me understand where i went wrong with my code. Also, if you have any advice on how i should have coded differently for this problem, please let me know!

I tried changing using a for loop but I'm reading online that its an iteration function and doesn't work with recursive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

void showInUpper(char alphabet[], int i);


int main()
{

char alphabet[27]{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
int i = 0;

showInUpper(alphabet, i);

cout << endl << endl;
}

void showInUpper(char alphabet[], int i)
{

if (alphabet[i] == '\0')
{
    return;

}

else if (alphabet[i] != toupper(alphabet[i]))
{
    alphabet[i] = toupper(alphabet[i]);
    cout << alphabet[i] << '\t';
}

showInUpper(alphabet, i++);
}
```

So, the expected results should look like this.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZXYZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the same value of `i` to each invocation of `showInUpper` because `i` doesn't get incremented until after it is passed to the function. As a result you have endless recursion.

Use the pre-increment operator instead:

```cpp
showInUpper(alphabet, ++i);
```

so that `i` is incremented before it is passed.

Comment: Wow! I never knew it mattered that much until now. Haha, thanks for your help!